# How can you replace macOS's bouncing dock icon animation?

Tags: macos, dock, icon, ui

I often find macOS's endlessly repeating "I want your attention" dock bounce animation irritating, so I disabled it with the command `defaults write com.apple.dock no-bouncing -bool TRUE` , followed by `killall Dock`.

I'd still like a visual cue when an app needs my attention, just a subtler one. Can the bouncing animation be replaced with a repeating toggle between the normal and translucent appearances of an dock icon, or some other low-distraction animation?

**NOTE:** The translucent dock icon appearance applies when an app is hidden. It can be enabled with `defaults write com.apple.Dock showhidden -bool TRUE`. To be clear, if I can replace the animation as suggested above, I don't want apps to be repeatedly hidden and shown while the animation is playing. That is what I assume would happen if, as would seem logical, the translucency adjustment controlled by `com.apple.Dock showhidden` can't be set independently of the actual hidden/visible status of the corresponding application.

Answer (score 3):

With regard to the ‘endlessly repeating’, you don't need to activate the app or otherwise deal with the issue being notified to you with the bounce.

Instead, move your mouse over the bouncing icon in the Dock. This will mute the app and stop the bouncing.